# Find vector product using structures in C

Tags: c, struct

I need to write function for calculating vector product of three vectors using structures in C. I have written function which works correct but I don't know how to print result.
Structures are new to me.

I get an error:

> format ‘%g’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘Vektor3d’ {aka ‘struct anonymous’}

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct{
    double x,y,z;
}     Vektor3d;

Vektor3d vector_product(Vektor3d v1, Vektor3d v2)
{
    Vektor3d v3;
    v3.x=(v1.y*v2.z-v1.z*v2.y);
    v3.y=(v1.z*v2.x-v1.x*v2.z);
    v3.z=(v1.x*v2.y-v1.y*v2.x);
    return v3;
}

int main() {
   Vektor3d v1,v2;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &v1.x, &v1.y, &v1.z);
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &v2.x, &v2.y, &v2.z);
    printf("%g", vector_product(v1, v2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `vector_product` returns an object of type `Vektor3d`. You can't use that directly inside `printf`. Save the return value in a variable, then print its components (x,y,z)

Comment: You know how to scanf a vector. Printf it the same way, minus `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
    printf("%g", vector_product(v1, v2));
```

`vector_product()` returns an object of type `Vektor3d`. The function `printf()` does not know how to print this object. You have to call `printf()` and pass to it only the types it can handle (e.g. integers, doubles, etc.)

To fix this, simply store the result object in a variable, then pass its components to `printf()`. That is,

```
int main() {
    Vektor3d v1,v2;
    Vektor3d v3;

    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &v1.x, &v1.y, &v1.z);
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &v2.x, &v2.y, &v2.z);
    v3 = vector_product(v1, v2);          /* Save the return value in v3 */
    printf("%g %g %g", v3.x, v3.y, v3.z); /* pass the components of v3 to printf */
    return 0;
}
```